# Как разрешить междоменные (CORS) запросы Open Server?

Tags: cors

Как разрешить междоменные запросы в Open-server?

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
```

в начале скрипта к которому хочешь разрешить такой запрос