# Как заполнить форму на другом сайте

Tags: javascript, ajax, база-данных, json

Всем привет. Мне нужно заполнить один input на другом сайте и нажать кнопку отправить, потом достать полученные данные. Как это можно реализовать с помощью js

Comment: Это можно сделать с помощью Puppeeter - https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer

Answer (score 0):

В общем случае - никак - в целях безопасности запрещаются кросс-доменные запросы. 
Только если на сайте, на который посылается запрос, они разрешены посредством отправки определенных заголовков (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`). Пример - [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/770825/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-cors-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-open-server)

Ну а как отправлять `ajax-запросы`, можно почитать [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-xmlhttprequest)

или использовать `Fetch Api/$.ajax` или что-то еще.